# Select the current category in wordpress, unexpected behavior

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

```php
<ul class="main-nav">
                <li class="menu-item <?php if( is_category('one') || in_category('one') ) echo 'current_cat'; ?>">
                    <a href="/category/one/">one</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item <?php if( is_category('two') || in_category('two') ) echo 'current_cat'; ?>">
                    <a href="/category/two/">two</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item <?php if( is_category('three') || in_category('three') ) echo 'current_cat'; ?>">
                    <a href="/category/three/">three</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item <?php if( is_category('four') || in_category('four') ) echo 'current_cat'; ?>">
                    <a href="/category/four/">four</a>
                </li>
                <li class="menu-item <?php if( is_category('five') || in_category('five') ) echo 'current_cat'; ?>">
                    <a href="/category/five/">five</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

The bottom line is that on the main page (index.php) is allocated category (in fact in theory this should not happen), a little closer examination I realized that the category in the main determined by the first post on a page - in which category he belongs. Suppose on the main page is present the latest news from the category of "2" - then the index page is the category of "2" ... What is the problem and how to fix it is not quite clear to me the behavior? What features are not taken into account? Thank you for your future answers.

And I ask forgiveness for broken English.

Comment: I don't get what you're asking exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, make sure that code is not running inside the loop, that might be the key problem. If this is happening even outside the loop, you can avoid it to be triggered on the home page by modifying your conditions like this:

```
if( is_category('one') || (in_category('one') and is_single()) )
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking, you don't want this code to trigger on the home page?

to make sure this is only run on individual post pages put this all between:

```
<?php if(is_single(): ?>
      <!-- your code-->
<?php endif; ?>
```

[is_single](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single)
stll I'm not sure what you are asking.